# How to escape special characters in CosmosDB index policies?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I want to index a property called `$Type` so that queries like
`SELECT * FROM c WHERE c["$Type"] = "User"` will be evaluated using an index.

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/index-policy#includeexclude-strategy) is not very clear regarding the expected syntax.
I tried to use `"path": "/$Type/?"` and `"/"$"Type/?"` but both aren't accepted.

The `$Type` property is used by our JSON serialization settings, and so I don't want to rename the property.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation lacks a forward slash in the index definition. The correct way to define this index is like:

`"path": "/\"$Type\"/?"`

Notice that entire `$Type` string is escaped - you can't escape just the `$` character.